# error requirements pyparsing 1.5.7 odoo 8

Tags: pip, odoo, pyparsing

I'm trying to install odoo 8 on my vps ubuntu 14.04, when I type pip install -r requirements.txt I get an error which I don't realy understand, I tried google etc.. nothing about it. So please can anyone help me with this, thanks.
here is the output:

```
    Collecting pyparsing==1.5.7 (from -r odoo-8.0-20170128/requirements.txt (line 25))
    Using cached pyparsing-1.5.7.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/odoo/venv_odoo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/opt/odoo/venv_odoo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/opt/odoo/venv_odoo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/opt/odoo/venv_odoo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wI4wxS/pyparsing/
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug, see https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12722

Upgrading to pyparsing 2.1.10 seems to fix it, else replace the line

```
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
```

in requirements.py of the packaging module with

```
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR)("marker")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a newer version of pyparsing already installed (pip itself uses it) and it produces a crash.

Try to install Odoo 8 in a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv odoo8
source odoo8/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```